# Menu appearing after a choice is made

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to Django and I'm unsure of whether I'm going in the right direction with this.

What I'm trying to do is, when the user is creating a Character in the Admin menu, if the user chooses faction Alliance, to bring up the Alliance_Races, and if not, the Horde_Races.

**models.py**

```
Factions = (
    ('Choose', 'Choose...'),
    ('Alliance','Alliance'),
    ('Horde', 'Horde'),
)


Alliance_Races = (
    ('Human','Human'),
    ('Dwarf', 'Dwarf'),
    ('Night Elf', 'Night Elf'),
    ('Gnome', 'Gnome'),
    ('Draenei', 'Draenei'),
    ('Worgen', 'Worgen'),
    ('Pandaren', 'Pandaren'),
)

Horde_Races = (
    ('Orc','Orc'),
    ('Undead', 'Undead'),
    ('Tauren', 'Tauren'),
    ('Troll', 'Troll'),
    ('Blood Elf', 'Blood Elf'),
    ('Goblin', 'Goblin'),
    ('Pandaren', 'Pandaren'),
)


class Character(models.Model):
    character_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    faction = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=Factions, default='none')
    race = ""

    def __str__(self):
        return self.character_name

    def race_options(self):
        if self.allied_with == "Alliance":
            self.race = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=Alliance_Races, default='none')
        elif self.allied_with == "Horde":
            self.race = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=Horde_Races, default='none')
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using model inheritance:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    character_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.character_name

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AllianceCharacter(Character)
    race = models.CharField(choices=Alliance_Races)

class HordeCharacter(Character)
    race = models.CharField(choices=Horde_Races)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution and I'm getting an error:
"The model Character is abstract, so it cannot be registered with admin."

Comment: This is my **admin.py** file:
class CharacterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ("character_name")
admin.site.register(Character, CharacterAdmin)

Comment: @IvanPenev you're trying to register an abstract model. You'll need to register each of the subclassed models: `admin.site.register(AllianceCharacter, CharacterAdmin)` and `admin.site.register(HordeCharacter, CharacterAdmin)`

Comment: I commented the line "admin.site.register(Character, CharacterAdmin)" and added the two lines you advised and the server runs well, but the outcome isn't quite what I was thinking of. When I go to the Admin screen, instead of Character, I now have AllianceCharacter and HordeCharacter and what I would've liked to have is one page where depending on whether I pick Alliance or Horde, to get the appropriate Races. Is that not doable?